# Posts in Edit View Not Populating... Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to populate an edit view in angular 1.x. My controllers are logging the value of "themenu" and "$scope.addmenu" but the data is not showing up in the text fields..

```
angular.module('sample.menu', [
'auth0'
]).controller('MenuCtrl', function HomeController($scope, $http, auth, $location, store) {

$scope.menus = {};
$scope.addmenu = {};

var res1 = $http.get('http://grubr2.webfacelab.com:8888/index.php/api/menu');
res1.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log(data);
  $scope.menus = data;
});
res1.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({ data: data }));
});



$scope.addMenu = function () {
  console.log('Adding Menu');
  console.log($scope.menu);
  var res = $http.post('http://grubr2.webfacelab.com:8888/index.php/api/menu', $scope.menu);
  res.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.message = data;
  });
  res.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({ data: data }));
  });

}

$scope.editThisMenu = function (themenu) {
  console.log("Edit this menu:");
  console.log(themenu);
  console.log("End menu data");

  $scope.addmenu = themenu;
  console.log($scope.addmenu);


}

$scope.updateMenu=function(){
  alert('Update menu!!');
}


});
```

And in my views Menus.html

```
<ion-view title="Menus">
<ion-content padding="'true'" class="has-header">
    <form class="list">
        <div class="list card">
            <div class="item item-divider">Menu Item</div>
            <div class="item item-body">
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item menu-close="" class="item-thumbnail-left">
                        <img>
                        <h2>Menu Item</h2>
                        <p>**Delicious</p>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
                <button class="button button-stable button-block ">Upload Picture</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ion-list>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Name</span>
                <input ng-model="menu.name" type="text" placeholder="">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Description</span><textarea ng-model="menu.description" placeholder=""> </textarea>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Price</span>
                <input ng-model="menu.price" type="number" placeholder="">
            </label>
        </ion-list>
        <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
        <button class="button button-stable button-block " ng-click="addMenu()">Add Menu</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="menu in menus">
        <li>{{menu.id}}: <a href="#/menu/{{menu.id}}" ng-click="editThisMenu(menu)">{{menu.name}}</a></li>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

And Menuedit.html which is supposed to display the content to be edited

```
<ion-view title="Menus">
<ion-content padding="'true'" class="has-header">
    <form class="list">
        <div class="list card">
            <div class="item item-divider">Edit Menu Item</div>
            <div class="item item-body">
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item menu-close="" class="item-thumbnail-left">
                        <img>
                        <h2>Menu Item</h2>
                        <p>**Delicious</p>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
                <button class="button button-stable button-block ">Edit Picture</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ion-list>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Name</span>
                <input ng-model="addmenu.name" type="text" placeholder="">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Description</span><textarea ng-model="addmenu.description" placeholder=""> </textarea>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Price</span>
                <input ng-model="addmenu.price" type="number" placeholder="">
            </label>
        </ion-list>
        <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
        <button class="button button-stable button-block " ng-click="updateMenu()">Update Menu</button>
    </form>
    <hr>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what's causing your problem, because I don't think you've provided enough information to say for certain.  But I think it has to do with your client-side routing.  In this: `<a href="#/menu/{{menu.id}}" ng-click="editThisMenu(menu)">{{menu.name}}</a></li>` you have what appears to be a link to a piece of your application.  The ng-click will not allow the route change so your template is most likely still `Menus.html` instead of `Menuedit.html`.

I want to address how you've constructed this module, though.  You have a lot of repetition in your templates that can be reduced with a simple flag on your scope.  Using a flag such as `$scope.isNew` would allow you to use the `ng-if` directive to toggle certain HTML elements off and on, depending if you're editing or creating a new menu.  I've added a bit of functionality as well, so bear with me.

I would set up your controller like this:

```
$scope.isNew = true; // flag to keep track of form state
$scope.menus = []; // initialize an empty array for the menus
$scope.menu = {}; // initialize an empty object for the form

var res1 = $http.get('mock.json');
res1
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.menus = data;
  })
  .error(function (data) {
    console.log("failure message: " + JSON.stringify(data));
  });

$scope.clear = function() {
  $scope.isNew = true;
  $scope.menu = {};
}

$scope.submit = function(menu) {
  if ($scope.isNew) {
    $scope.menus.push(menu);
  } else {
    $scope.menus[$scope.currentIndex] = menu;
  }
  $scope.clear();
}

$scope.remove = function() {
  $scope.menus.splice($scope.currentIndex, 1);
  $scope.clear();
}

$scope.edit = function(menu, index) {
  $scope.currentIndex = index;
  $scope.isNew = false;

  // this has to be copied so it's not two-way bound to the template
  $scope.menu = angular.copy(menu);
}
```

As you can see, I've add an `isNew` flag and a `clear` function to the scope.  I've also added a `currentIndex` to the scope for when editing is enabled.  `currentIndex` is used when deleting an item (part of the functionality I added), since the button for deletion is sitting outside of the scope of the item being deleted.  The `clear` function will reset the form and switch the `isNew` flag.  I've changed the `addMenu` function in your original code to `submit` so that the term better represents its ability to submit an edit or new menu.

And now for the template:

```
<section class="has-header" ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
  <button ng-if="!isNew" class="button button-stable button-block" ng-click="clear()">New Menu</button>
  <form class="list">
    <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-divider">Menu Item</div>
        <div class="item item-body">
            <div>
                <div menu-close="" class="item-thumbnail-left">
                    <img>
                    <h2>Menu Item</h2>
                    <p>**Delicious</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="button button-stable button-block ">Upload Picture</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Name</span>
            <input ng-model="menu.name" type="text" placeholder="">
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Description</span><textarea ng-model="menu.description" placeholder=""> </textarea>
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Price</span>
            <input ng-model="menu.price" type="number" placeholder="">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
    <button class="button button-stable button-block " ng-click="submit(menu)">
      <span ng-if="isNew">Add Menu</span>
      <span ng-if="!isNew">Update Menu</span>
    </button>
    <button ng-if="!isNew" class="button button-stable button-block" ng-click="remove()">Delete Menu</button>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <div ng-repeat="menu in menus track by $index">
    <li>{{menu.id}}: <a ng-click="edit(menu, $index)">{{menu.name}}</a></li>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've added a button at the top to create a new menu, that's only displayed if you're in edit mode.  All it does is clear the form.  I've added a check for `isNew` for the submit button as well, changing whether it says "Update" or "Add" based on `isNew`.  And I added a "Remove" button, only shown when in edit mode.  Hopefully I've explained my thinking clearly, because I feel like this is a much better approach to your problem.  Feel free to ask questions for any clarifications.  I've also created a Plunk to demonstrate all of this.  http://plnkr.co/edit/gvP2iUahPjhzTmByPQw6?p=preview